# How can I place images (variable number of them) relatively to each other and also scale jumbotron they are in accordingly? Django

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, frontend

I wanted to ask you for your help. I fought with it for quite a long time but I couldn't come up with good solutions. This is my first project in Django and HTML/CSS/js so I am sorry in advance :P

I created two images that will help me explain my problem:

[image]

In this case, I have three images, png with alpha. The actual image is in red "I-1". The darker border is actual image size. By default they of course stack like that. And yellow is other stuff.

When I place them ether by position relative or absolute it looks like that:

[image]

And it is also quite logical why this happens. This is kinda what I want to achieve. But there are two/three problems:

1.1 - Other stuff for the website is way down, this looks weird and I don't like that.

1.2 - My jumbotron also is stretched way down.

2 - I have a different amount of images in various cases. Sometimes there are 3 of them and sometimes 5 of them. And each one of them I need to place a little bit different. That is a big problem for me.

I managed to create three types of them, when first(1) and last one(5) are always the same so it is cool, but 2, 3 and 4 in the middle needs a little bit different position.

I am new in Django, CSS, and HTML so to be honest, I don't even know how I should google that. I will be very grateful for any help and tips.

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched internet and experimented for some time. And right now my best solution is css "scale".

I went with for example:

```
#head {
     scale: 3.5;
     z-index: 5;
}
```

And it is working quite well! First I add small images (like 100px) and then scale them up in CSS. This way they are aligned nicely and also don't take much space below them. By scaling up my "I-1", "I-2" etc. from my examples are next to each other and they don't take space around them.

It is certainly not an very elegant solution but it works :)